# Библиотека для чтения значений с игрового руля

Tags: python

Хотел бы узнать, есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для чтения значений с игрового руля?

Comment: Есть. Если руль подключен по усб, то библиотека для работы с усб, если руль воткнут в серийный вход, то библиотека для работы с серийным входом (pyserial, например), и т.д.

Comment: Вроде бы в SDL есть средства для работы с игровыми контполлерами. Так что имеет смысл попробовать pySDL

Comment: если руль как joystick виден, то можно pygame.joystick использовать (что относительно низкоуровнево, но выше чем пытаться с usb данные напрямую читать). [Пример для Logitech G27  руля](https://github.com/schmerdy/openxc-wheel/blob/master/wheel.py)¶ Избегайте вопросов: "какую библиотеку использовать в некой нише" лучше спросить "как сделать конкретную вещь X имея конкретное устройство Y"

Comment: related: [Reading joystick values with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19203819/4279)